# Rails url_for not finding the route which appears in Rake Routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have following from rake routes:

```
user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                                     {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
```

But when I do, for an email template:

```
<%= link_to(@comment.user.full_name, user_url(:only_path => false), :style => 'color:#5196E3;text-decoration:underline;') %>
```

I get the following error: "ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}):"

Thoughts? Thanks

Comment: `:style => 'color:#5196E3;text-decoration:underline;'` - I think it would be better to put this in your CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the route it needs an :id to parse. So you should supply the user like this:

```
user_url(@comment.user, :only_path => false)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is sometimes confusing.  Notice in your rake output, that the routing engine is expecting an id.  if it doesn't get one, it doesn't recognize the route.  Here's how you do it in controllers/views:

```
user_url(@comment.user)
```

or

```
user_url(@comment.user.id)
```